# Extrude Curve Between Two Paths

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, topology

I'm trying to create a beveled edge with a smooth transition from one radius to another as you can seen in the image below.

[image: TaperedCurve]

The primary selection is the path I want the secondary selection to follow while it tapers down to smaller radius bevel of the existing geometry.

Both the inner and outer "tracks" that the bevel should follow have the same number of segments (6) so the final shape should have 24 faces (6 segments x 3 beveled faces per segment). I hope that makes it clear what I'm trying to accomplish.

I think I can create the geometry fairly easily by hand using curves between each segment, but I thought there might be a more elegant way to dot it.

I've read a few topics ([32571](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32571/deform-mesh-along-two-curves), [34763](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34763/interpolate-mesh-surface-between-curves), [31211](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/will-warp-bridge-these-two-objects)) that I thought might help but haven't been able to get anything to work yet.

I'm quite new to Blender so I hope I'm not overlooking something simple.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See the BSurfaces Addon [Blender artists thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225190-Bsurfaces-v1-5), and [Wiki page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5)  if you want to do it directly from curve objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing you may use the *Grid Fill* operator, as long as all opposing loops have the exact same number of edges, and belong to the same mesh object.

[image]

If you want to use actual Bezier Curve objects as guids for lofting, you may look into using the BSurfaces Addon. See the [Blender artists thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225190-Bsurfaces-v1-5), or it's [Wiki page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5).

This sort of thing is usually best modeled with either NURBS or Solid Modelling CAD based software, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Grid fill did the job well enough for my current needs but I will keep your other suggestions in mind for the future.