# Add Edge to face deleted

Tags: vertices, faces

I removed faces from my object. It is mirrored but I want to add faces back to form an L shape closing the geometry with faces.[image]
I highlighted where I want to add the lines. How do i do this with its vertices so I can still select them and fill them with <kbd>F</kbd>?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, see if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58844/extrude-curve-between-two-paths/58852#58852

Comment: I essentially want to fill the empty faces with faces that meet at a 90 degree where the purple line is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select the front two middle edges (like in the image below).
   [image: selected edges to extrude]
2. Turn on vertex (or edge) snapping, and extrude those selected edges along the Y axis to the middle.
   [image: extruding]
3. Now select the pairs of edges to create the new faces.
   In this image I already filled one face and have another selection ready for filling.
   [image: creating faces]

Do note that this does create a triangle in the corner, depending of what you are going to do with this mesh that may be undesirable.

---

Now here is an animated gif of the whole process.
[image: animated gif of the whole process]

Another way, if you have the [F2 addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42017/2217) enabled, is to select the corer vertex and simply press <kbd>F</kbd>. Repeat for the bottom three faces. Then fill the vertical faces like before.
[image: another animated gif]